# Where in Ireland, if anywhere, at the time of James Joyce, would "hoe" and "whore" sound similar enough to pun?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, rhoticity, hiberno-english

Where in Ireland, if anywhere, at the time of James Joyce (1882 – 1941), would "hoe" and "whore" sound similar enough to pun?

This question pertains to [Does Joyce, in Finnegans Wake or Ulysses, link the sound form “hoe” to “whore”?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/10903/does-joyce-in-finnegans-wake-or-ulysses-link-the-sound-form-hoe-to-whore) from our sister site for [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com).

The first issue is rhoticity. While most of the English world is non-rhotic, according to [Rhoticity in English - Ireland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English#Ireland)

> The prestige form of English spoken in Ireland is rhotic and most
>   regional accents are rhotic although some regional accents,
>   particularly in the area around counties Louth and Cavan are notably
>   non-rhotic and many non-prestige accents have touches of
>   non-rhoticity. *In Dublin, the traditional local dialect is largely
>   non-rhotic*,
>   but the more modern varieties, referred to by Hickey as "mainstream
>   Dublin English" and "fashionable Dublin English", are fully rhotic.

The Dublin non-rhoticity is why Joyce could successfully pun "haw" and "whore" in *Ulysses*. He heard the pun in real life *(and of course all the non-rhotic English world would potentially get it)*.

But a "hoe"-"hoer"-"whore" pun requires non-rhoticity *and* a coincidence of vowel form pronunciations. That such a coincidence might occur somewhere in Ireland is suggested by my lay reading of Wikipedia’s [Hiberno-English: Overview of pronunciation and phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiberno-English#Overview_of_pronunciation_and_phonology).

---

The modern day US "ho"-"whore" can only be traced back only to the sixties.

Comment: Modern day Irish may use the term [cute hoor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cute_hoor).

Comment: From that Wikipedia article it looks like all the dialects in Ireland are rhotic so it would be strange for any of them to match how and white. But they _are_ close and the difference wouldn't prevent Joyce from making a pun.

Comment: Non-rhoticity allowed Joyce to pun "haw" and "whore" in Ulysses, but "hoe"-"hoer"-"whore" also requires further a  Hiberno-English vowel coincidence, which theoretically exists, but I am not sure where, how common, or if it really sounds similar. Joyce would have to hear it to pun it.

Comment: After reading the other post, the claim feels like too much of a stretch. In many instances of *ho*, there are perhaps a few where substituting *whore* would lead to something that makes sense, but that seems anachronistic at best since *ho* with that meaning is unattested. Furthermore, while the pronunciation question may be interesting in itself, I don't think it demonstrates a relationship between the two words in-text, any (Annie) more (Sir Thomas More) than *weight* has (hazmat) to (two) be (bee) a (uh) pun (punishment) for (four) *wait* or (oar) vice (vies) versa (Nissan Versa).

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin The coincidence riddles Finnegans Wake, it is everywhere. I will pull an example: "Face at the waist! Ho, you fie!", her face is at his waist, Ho, you disgust! But again, ho-whore, and mimicking "Whore. Fie, whore'" from The Dutch Courtesan. So many such links, in FW. I accepted the answer on lit,  because I needed a line in the sand, but... I know FW backwards..., Just need you folks to also draw it for me I suppose.

Comment: @fundagain Sure, Ho and whore, are similar enough even in rhotic dialects to make a literary pun. They don't have to be exact equals. And Joyce was probably well aware of the standard non-rhotic RP literary accent so that the pun would work better for most of his intended readers.

Comment: @Mitch I counter this, to myself, by pointing out that nowhere in the literature has anyone made this observation, despite 24 "ho"s in the Circes ("whore") chapter of Ulysses. Why did no one notice?

Comment: @fundagain Reading the wiki page more closely: ["The local Dublin accent is the only one that during an earlier time was non-rhotic, "](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiberno-English#Local_Dublin_English). This I suppose is enough to answer your question?

Comment: @Mitch, but how does that square with "...although some regional accents, particularly in the area around counties Louth and Cavan are notably non-rhotic and many non-prestige accents have touches of non-rhoticity." from the second wiki? [Rhoticity in Ireland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English#Ireland)

Comment: @fundagain as to squaring away, Wikipedia is as trustworthy as... well it's trustworthy when it confirms facts that you already knew (and you yourself are trustworthy!). Wikipedia is not written by a consistent and complete transcendental overseer of all knowledge. Each sentence is written possibly by a different person (or rather -many- people, modifying each sentence). I've never been to Dublin, or have heard of Louth or Cavan (are those near Dublin?). So I don't actually know anything. (and even if I did , there'd be no guarantee that I'd know)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95943/discussion-between-fundagain-and-mitch).

Comment: James Joyce never saw two words he couldn't pun.

Comment: @Robusto "Thus the hearsomeness[whore-someness] of the burger felicitates the whole of the polis", from Dublin's motto "Obidientia civium urbis felicitas" via *gehorsam* (ger) - obedient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Though the generic Irish-English accent is rhotic (pronounces all 'r's), Supposedly, the accent in Dublin, where Joyce was born and raised, [is (or was at that time?) non-rhotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiberno-English#Local_Dublin_English). In that case, 'hoe' /hoʊ̯/ or /ho:/ and 'whore' /hoːɹ/ or /ho:/, are pretty close.
- Joyce, being well-educated, might have been explicitly writing for a more general British audience which would  more likely be non-rhotic. (this is pure speculation).
- Puns don't have to be exact matches to invoke comparison. Witness all the horrible knock-knock jokes where the name standing a lone gets twisted into something nearby simply to make a tenuous connection for a 6 year old:

  > Knock knock.
  >
  > Who’s there?
  >
  > Mustache.
  >
  > Mustache who?
  >
  > I mustache you a question, but I’ll shave it for later.

  This is only to address the issue that Joyce could be writing with an entirely rhotic ear and still be trying to make puns. I mean, it'd be easier to point out the few places where there's *not* a pun.
- disclaimer: I don't have much familiarity with Irish accents. I'm passing on information I've gathered from elsewhere.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I will accept the highest voted post at end of bounty period.

Comment: @fundagain I really hope other jump in with data other than from wikipedia

Comment: What a terrible excuse for a pun. It's a good job it's a good one.

Answer (score 1):

**The Null Hypothesis: Nowhere!**

Certainly *non-rhoticity*, both of Joyce's Dublin English and the English of his typically readers, allowed Joyce, the pun-master, especially in *Finnegans Wake*, to pun haw-hoor-hoer with "whore". In fact, he punned "haw" and "whore" in the "Circes", the "whore" chapter of *Ulysses*. Even "hear"-"whore".

On the other hand, the idea that Joyce could see "hoe" (or "ho") as punning with "whore" is improbable.

---

While essentially immaterial to the argument, it should be noted that

1. the modern day term "ho" for "whore" can only be [traced to the 1960's](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ho),
2. and no one in the literature has ever suggested that Joyce was making such a pun, which suggests none of Joyce's readers see such a pun!

---

But it is not about rhoticity, rather, is is about vowel pronunciation!

Consider the two words Joyce commonly uses for whore,  "whore" ("haw") and "hoer", and compare them to "hoe" and "ho".

```
whore      as in oar  
hoer       as in lure
hoe        as in oh
ho         as in oh
```

No English speaker, let alone Irish English speaker, would every pronounce "ho" *(oh)* or "hoe" *(oh)* with the same vowel sound as the would "whore" *(oar)* or "hoer" *(lure)*.

Hence Joyce would never have heard these words be pronounced sufficiently closely for him to see a pun.

---

- If you think I am wrong, please vote me down. I will remove the post if negative at the end of the bounty period.
- If you think I am correct, then please vote me up!
- If someone gives a better negative answer than me, please vote them up. In such a case, I will delete this post and award the bonus to the alternative negative, if it beats the best positive answer.
- This really is just to ensure a voteable null-hypothesis, that can be used to disagree with Mitch without voting him down.
- In other words, I think Joyce *might* easily have made the pun, but I need you to say it. That he *did*, of course, only [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) can decide.