# Does the usage of "ho" or "hoe" for "whore" predate the 20th century?

Tags: etymology

In [Medieval Pleasures: What Was Sex Really Like In The Middle Ages?](https://youtu.be/R8JPN9tWVPQ?t=100), Leeds Trinity professor [Dr. Kate Lister](https://research.leedstrinity.ac.uk/en/persons/kate-lister) shows how the records of medieval British street names reveal secrets regarding illicit activities. She sites "Grape Lane", "Whore's Mount", "Sit Down Ho", etc.

It is the latter, "Sit Down Ho", that I am most interested in.

- **Was "ho" or "hoe" every used for "whore" prior to the 20th century?**

I tried but failed to find Dr Lister's references (I am behind a science only paywall).

This question relates to the questions

- [Where in Ireland, if anywhere, at the time of James Joyce, would "hoe" and "whore" sound similar enough to pun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/504177/where-in-ireland-if-anywhere-at-the-time-of-james-joyce-would-hoe-and-whor), and
- [Does Joyce, in Finnegans Wake or Ulysses, link the sound form "hoe" to "whore"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/10903/does-joyce-in-finnegans-wake-or-ulysses-link-the-sound-form-hoe-to-whore).

If "ho" or "hoe" were used for "whore" prior to the 20th century, both these questions have simple answers.

Comment: One early variant form is "hoor"—which appears in Walter Scott's [_Rob Roy_](https://books.google.com/books?id=WRkGAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA113&dq=%22hoor%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_r9rpgNz4AhUzK0QIHePdBnc4FBDoAXoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22hoor%22&f=false) (1817): "'The servants,' he stated 'with the tenantry and others, had been all regularly enrolled and mustered, and they wanted me to take arms also. But I'll ride in nae siccan troop—they little kenn'd Andrew that asked him. I'll fight when I like mysell, but it sall neither be for the hoor of Babylon, nor ony hoor in England.'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/248633?rskey=esL4Ln&result=6&isAdvanced=false#eid) (possibly paywalled) indicates that this use of *ho* does not predate the twentieth century, and does not list this meaning for *hoe* at all.

> Forms:  1900s– **ho**, 1900s– **'ho**, 1900s– **ho'**, 1900s– **hoah**, 1900s– **hoe**, 1900s– **who'**, 1900s– **whoe**.
>
> Etymology: Variant of **whore** *n.,* reflecting a pronunciation frequent in African-American usage.

The earliest citation is from 1964. However, *ho/hoe* is similar enough to *whore* that it **could** have been used with that meaning, but wouldn't necessarily have been written down. But if a placename like "Sit Down Ho" actually exists and actually has that etymology I think I would have expected OED to include it.

For what it's worth, it seems to me that Joyce's usages of *ho* in [the passages you cite](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/10903) are so obscure as to not be double-entendres, and I agree with [your other answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/504744/18696).

Comment: Thanks. I upvoted, because your OED argument is strong (and has always ben my expected null hypothesis to this question generally). I still hope someone can dig a bit on Lister's evidence. I am trying. Ho puns appear so routinely in *Finnegans Wake* that I am forced to dig.

Comment: I have read Kate Listers book, and there is no mention. So am accepting.